# NEST2 SetBasicAuthentication() is gone?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, elasticsearch, nest

On my NEST 1.0 project I was using the API:

```
SetBasicAuthentication(elasticUser, elasticPassword);
```

Now it's gone, what's the replacement for it?

Comment: Are you looking for `BasicAuthentication` on `ConnectionSettings`?

Comment: I'm looking for ConnectionSettings

Comment: Ok found it, they removed the "Set" from the method name

Comment: Take a look at the breaking changes for 2.x, in particular the list of diffs - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/tree/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes. We've tried to capture all the changes programmatically as best as possible so most of them should be there